# Virtualenvwrapper not persisting between terminal windows

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I successfully installed Virtualenvwrapper and am able to use it after running source .bashrc: The only problem is, that the commands do not work if I start a new terminal window or if I re-start the terminal. How do I remedy this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Add the following line to your .bash_profile:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Longer answer:**

By default, Terminal starts the shell via /usr/bin/login, which makes the shell a login shell. On every platform (not just Mac OS X) bash does not use .bashrc for login shells (only /etc/profile and the first of .bash_profile, .bash_login, .profile that exists and is readable). This is why “put source ~/.bashrc in your .bash_profile” is standard advice.

(this answer was originally posted here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12993/why-doesnt-bashrc-run-automatically#comment13715_13019)